# scan if value of one table are in other ones without joining

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was wondering if there is a way in bigquery to scan if value of one table are in other one without doing traditional joinings since is complicated for my use case.

For example i have table `phones`

```
         phone
+4915739064510
+4915739062389
+4983149315893
```

And other table that is `service_provider` with info like this

```
service_code service_name
      +49157     Vodafone
     +498314        Telco
```

And my expected output would create a new column in `phones` where shows the `service_name` of the `phone`, notice that `service_code` length can vary, this is just some example but in reality `service_code` length can go from 4 to 10 making hard to join by a specific length value from `phone`

Expected output

```
         phone    service_name 
+4915739064510        Vodafone
+4915739062389        Vodafone
+4983149315893           Telco
```

Wanted to know if there is a way to accomplish such a thing ?

Comment: meantime, I realized you are asking for solution **without joining**?? what do you mean really? both below answers are based on joining and honestly I don't see way to not to using some kind of join. Please clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this utilizing the `STARTS_WITH` function

```
select 
  phone,
  service_name
from phone_numbers, service 
where 
  starts_with(phone, service_code) = TRUE
```

This should accommodate varying lengths of input.  If there is a scenario where multiple criteria match you can then apply additional logic to rank and filter down to one.

More information on the `STARTS_WITH` function can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#starts_with

Answer (score 0):

Or just simplified/refactored version of already given answer

```
select phone, service_name
from phones
join service_provider
on starts_with(phone, service_code)
```

with output

[image]